# Psapi.lib not found when project is created by cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a cmake that create a project for VS 2019. When I try to compile the code, I am getting that this library is not found:

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64\Psapi.Lib'
```

Checking my system, I do not have 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits' directory.

I made sure that during my VS installation, the C++ code development was selected and also I run a repair on installation to ensure that any missing file is installed, but I m still have the same issue.

What other software or library should I install to get this issue fixed?

Comment: I have a Windows Kits folder installed by Visual Studio Community 2019. I think this is installed when you install any of Windows SDKs in the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: I checked VS and windows SDK is installed but I do not have a such directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have Visual Studio  2022 and installed Win10 SDK **10.0.19041.0** via Visual Studio installer Desktop Development With C++. I am able to find Psapi.lib in directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64`. Try installing  SDK from page: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/